# Find element in array inside array and return element with parent object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Given...

```
    var a = [{ b: [{ i: 2 }, { i: 3 }] }, { b: [{ i: 4 }, { i: 5 }] }, { b: [{ i: 6 }, { i: 7 }] }];
```

What is a good way to find the object, for example, with `i = 5` plus the object that contains the array that it's in?

So, the result would be two references...

```
var r0 = { "i": 5 };
var r1 = { "b": [{ "i": 4 }, { "i": 5 } ]};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for both iterations, because if found, the iterations stop by returning `true`.

This proposal returns the first found elements on which the condition is `true`.

```js
var array = [{ b: [{ i: 2 }, { i: 3 }] }, { b: [{ i: 4 }, { i: 5 }] }, { b: [{ i: 6 }, { i: 7 }] }],
    i = 5,
    r0, r1;

array.some(function (a) {
    return a.b.some(function (b) {
        if (b.i === i) {
            r0 = b;
            r1 = a;
            return true;
        }
    });
});

console.log(r0);
console.log(r1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `forEach`:

```js
var a = [{ b: [{ i: 2 }, { i: 3 }] }, { b: [{ i: 4 }, { i: 5 }] }, { b: [{ i: 6 }, { i: 7 }] }];

var r0;
var r1;
a.forEach(function(item){
  item.b.forEach(function(inner){
    if(inner.i==5){
      r0 = inner; r1 = item;
    }
  });
});
console.log(r0);
console.log(r1);
```

Comment: But the `foreach` doesn't short circuit when it's found the elements.

Comment: really `if true return false else return true`? with a global variable? and not using the return value of the inner `every`?

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var a = [{ b: [{ i: 2 }, { i: 3 }] }, { b: [{ i: 4 }, { i: 5 }] }, { b: [{ i: 6 }, { i: 7 }] }];
var result = a.filter(x => x.b.find(b => b.i == 5));
console.log(result)
```

Or using normal functions:

```js
var a = [{ b: [{ i: 2 }, { i: 3 }] }, { b: [{ i: 4 }, { i: 5 }] }, { b: [{ i: 6 }, { i: 7 }] }];
var result = a.filter(function (x) { 
  return x.b.find(function(b) { 
    return b.i == 5;
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, but I'm after a reference to `{ "i": 5 }` and `{ "b": [{ "i": 4 }, { "i": 5 } ]}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution may be different based on your actual background, like which factors you are considering are the most important such as time, space, read/write efficiency etc.

Below are two solutions for basic usage:

```js
var a = [{ b: [{ i: 2 }, { i: 3 }] }, { b: [{ i: 4 }, { i: 5 }] }, { b: [{ i: 6 }, { i: 7 }] }]

//The commom way: it has to loop whole array for each query
queryItem1 = function(searchTarget, searchVal) {
  return searchTarget.filter(
    function(val){
      return val.b.filter(function(item){return item.i===searchVal;}).length>0;
    }
  )
}

console.log('---common way----')
console.log(queryItem1(a, 5))
console.log('---end----')

//Considering `query` efficiency; 
//build index once, then query by one step instead of loop
buildIndexes = function(target) {
  let indexes = new Object();
  for(index in target) {
    for(itemIndex in target[index].b) {
      let queryVal = target[index].b[itemIndex].i;
      let queryIndex = index;
      if(!indexes[queryVal]) {
        indexes[queryVal] = [];
      }
      indexes[queryVal].push(queryIndex);
    }
  }
  return indexes;
}
console.log('---consider `query` efficiency way----')
indexes = buildIndexes(a)
//console.log(indexes)  //display index tree
console.log('---test case 1----')
console.log(indexes[5])  //if query vale is 5, get the index, then call like a[indexes[5][0]]
console.log(a[indexes[5][0]])
console.log('---test case 2----')
console.log(indexes[6])  //if query vale is 6, get the index, then call like a[indexes[6][0]]
console.log(a[indexes[6][0]])
console.log('---end----')
```